# Do ranked games matter in the pre-season?

Tags: league-of-legends

Currently, League of Legends is in between seasons but the ranked queue is still active. Does playing ranked games serve any purpose at the moment? Will it carry over directly into the next season or be used for seeding the initial rank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ranked games played in between Season 2 and Season 3 count for your Season 3 ranking; it'll be directly carried over.

There are plenty of sources; here's [one of them](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?s=&t=2852940).